# Extremum of $f:(\mathbb{R_+})^n \to \mathbb{R}$, $f(x_1,\dots ,x_2)=(1+x_1)\cdots(1+x_n)$ with $x_1 \cdots x_n=a^n$ for a fixed $a>0$

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier

$f:(\mathbb{R_+})^n \to \mathbb{R}$

$f(x_1,\dots ,x_2)=(1+x_1)\cdots(1+x_n)$

I want to determine where $f$ has a local or global extremum with the condition $x_1 \cdots x_n=a^n$ for a fixed $a>0$ using lagrange multipliers. How can this be done?

Comment: Have your tried writing out the Lagrangian and looking for its stationary point(s)? It turns out to be quite straightforward to solve the system of equations for the stationary points(s).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Showing that for real $0&lt;x_i, 0&lt;q$ with $x_1....x_n=q^n$ it holds that $(1+x_1)...(1+x_n)\geq(1+q)^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2860801/showing-that-for-real-0x-i-0q-with-x-1-x-n-qn-it-holds-that-1x-1)

Answer (score 0):

The general strategy would be as follows:

- Compute the gradient of $f$, i.e. $\nabla f$
- Give a name to your constraint, e.g. $g$ and compute its gradient too, i.e. $\nabla g$
- Introduce a Lagrange multiplier $\lambda$ and consider the two equations
  $$
  \begin{cases}
  \nabla f + \lambda \nabla g & = 0 \\
  g & = 0
  \end{cases}
  $$
  to be solved on the domain of $f$, i.e. $(\mathbb R_+)^n$.

That being said, if seems that you would have an easier time working with logarithms for that particular problem, which may also give you an intuition about the solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Calling

$$
L(x,\lambda) = \prod_{k=1}^n(1+x_k)-\lambda\left(\prod_{k=1}^n x_k - a^n\right)
$$

we have the stationary points as solutions for

$$
\nabla L =\begin{cases}
\frac{\prod_{k=1}^n(1+x_k)}{1+x_k}-\frac{\lambda \prod_{k=1}^n x_k}{x_k} = 0,\ \ k = 1,\cdots ,n\\
\prod_{k=1}^n x_k - a^n = 0
\end{cases}
$$

now calling

$$
\mu = \lambda\frac{\prod_{k=1}^n x_k}{\prod_{k=1}^n(1+x_k)}
$$

we have

$$
\frac{1}{1+x_k}-\frac{\mu}{x_k} = 0,\ \ k = 1,\cdots, n
$$

or

$$
x_k = \frac{1-\mu}{\mu}\Rightarrow \frac{1-\mu}{\mu} = a \Rightarrow \mu = \frac{1}{a+1}
$$

hence the solution $x_k = a$ is extremal